# Using custom settings for WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, windows, com, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to build an c# application that uses the WebBrowser Control for, obviouly, webbrowsing. To enhance the security of the system, i'd like to set my own security settings. These are two of the settings i would like to set through the software:

1. Disable Download for certain file-extensions (*.exe)
2. Disable Cookies

I found, that the WebBrowser Class directly uses the settings from Internet Explorer. Is there any way to use own settings for a specific WebBrower or overide these settings (maybe just temporarely)?

I think the Question may be similar to this:
[Overriding IE settings when embedding a WebBrowser control using IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850911/overriding-ie-settings-when-embedding-a-webbrowser-control-using-ie9)
(But i'm not sure... :)

**EDIT:** If I change the Cookie-Settings for Internet Explorer, they will be used for my WebBrowser-Control, right? Is it possible to change these global Settings via C#? Maybe this could be an easy solution for the Problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can disable cookies, though you can clear them; however, when you do so, you will be clearing cookies for *all* IE instances on that PC (for that particular account).  [Here is a StackOverflow with more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428509/clearing-cs-webbrowser-controls-cookies-for-all-sites-without-clearing-for-ie).

As far as controlling which files may be downloaded, you probably need to use some form of the [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Class.  [Here is a StackOverflow expanding on that with an example in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998084/can-someone-provide-a-link-to-a-useful-inheritancedemand-example).

Last, explore the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) for the Webbrowser control class, and you might get closer to what you need.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.

The links seem quite complicated, so i think i'll take me some time to understand... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust which files that can be downloaded by using the Navigating event of a webbrowser...

For Example, in the "Navigating" event for your web browser control...

```
if (e.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".exe"))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```